# Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: error : Could not find a part of the path '/platforms'

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to debug this error from past 3 days but still unable to solve it. Hope anyone of you can help me and probably others in future.

Where its failing: Whenever I try to deploy the app, deployment fails, with this error:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2112,3): error : Could not find a part of the path '/platforms'.
Though prior to this there are few warnings as well like,

1. AndroidManifest.xml //uses-sdk/@android:targetSdkVersion '21' is less than $(TargetFrameworkVersion) 'v7.0'. Using API-24 for ACW compilation
2. Some random conflicts.

But these are only warnings, and I shouldn't be concern about them.

What I did so far:

1. Uninstall/Install Visual studio
2. Tried downloading Xamarin studio through its dmg, thinking its IDE issue, but in vain.
3. Downloaded all relevant android sdk platforms.
4. Deleted/Again loaded the whole project.

but everything in vain. I will be highly thankful if anyone can help me in resolving this or atleast guiding me right direction.

Note: My visual studio version is 7.0.1, if this is of some help.

A more detailed error: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: Error: Could not find a part of the path '/platforms'.  at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError (System.Int32 errorCode, System.String maybeFullPath) [0x00207] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/io/__error.cs:188

**Solved it myself**:

**Added the ndk path from Tools -> Add Custom tools -> SDK location -> Android. Look for ndk path, enter the same and run.**

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Could you try it in an empty blank project? If the problem doesn't appear, could you share a basic demo that can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Did that too... Rather removed the whole IDE and reinstalled it again, but still the same error is coming. The problem occurs when I try to upload the build on device or emulator. Build generation is fine. Show me error on deployment.

Comment: Have you tried to deploy it in other emulators or devices?

Comment: I don't know what's the meaning of this.. Done building target "_BuildApkEmbed" in project "/Users/Projects/Droid/Droid.csproj".-- FAILED

Answer (score 2):

I found many people asking this same question, but very few answers.

First, if you get the error saying it can't find **c:/platforms** (or d:/platforms etc.  depending on which drive the project is stored on.) it is probably because you don't have Android NDK installed.  I thought this would have been installed with Xamarin, but - Nope.

In Visual Studio 2017, Navigate to **Tools menu --> Options --> Xamarin --> Android Settings.**
Notice the Andriod SDK Location  and **Andriod NDK Location**.  In my case, the NDK was blank.

I downloaded the NDK from https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/ and then unzipped it to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-ndk-r12b"
The problem is which version to download.  At this time, version r19 Beta 2 is the current release, but a known bug in Xamarin causes this NDK to throw other errors when you try to archive.  According to https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=48678, Version r12b is the last version to work with Xamarin.  Therefore it went to the NDK site, clicked on older versions, and choose the r12b 32bit version, downloaded, unzipped, and then saved that path in Tools menu --> Options --> Xamarin --> Android Settings-->Android NDK Location.
This solved many problems and allowed a successful Archive.

Answer (score 1):

Go to:

```
Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings
```

Changing `Archives Location` in settings worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The path of Android sdk location you are pointing to the project maybe changed.
Check in visual studio Tools->Option->Xamarin->Android settings

Comment: Android sdk location is fine. Just checked.

Answer (score 0):

install ndk, then setting ndk path：Tools->Option->Xamarin->Android settings
this is my ndk path:C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c